# Delete milions of files in a directory without listing them all at once

Tags: php, file

We have a `sessions` folder in outdated **Magento** installation,
that need to be manually cleaned from older files.

This is the current code:

```
private function _rrmdirContent($dir)
{
    $items = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $path = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item;
        is_dir($path) ? $this->_rrmdir($path) : unlink($path);
    }
}
```

It loads a ton of resources if the file list is to long (1000 000 000 files -> 4gb  memory limit exception)

Is there a way to remove the files one by one (ideally with some date created check), .. without loading them all at once?

Comment: Why don't you just open a shell and `rm -rf` that directory?

Comment: Rather than use scandir(), which loads the entire directory listing into a PHP array (hence consuming memory) use [opendir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php), [readdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) and [closedir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.closedir.php) to process each entry individually in memory

Comment: or still in php `exec('rm -rf')`

Comment: If you need to perform some checks before removing, you may use `DirectoryIterator` or `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`.

Comment: As for a date related check, test using the filesystem functions or fileinfo for each file

Comment: Needless to say, be extremely careful if you finally opt for issuing a `rm` system call from PHP, esp. if you don't pass a properly escaped absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the best way is to use [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) is also available but it's quite poorly documented so I stick with DirectoryIterator.

Function to recursively delete all files in directory could look like this

```
function clearDirectory($path, $rmDir = false)
{
    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach ($iterator as $item) {
        if ($item->isDot()) {
            continue; // skip dot dirs
        }
        if ($item->isDir()) {
            clearDirectory($item->getPathname(), true);
        } else {
            unlink($item->getPathname());
        }
    }
    if ($rmDir) {
        rmdir($iterator->getPathname());
    }
}
```

To clear directory `PATH` call

```
clearDirectory(PATH);
```

If you want to delete root directory at the end, use second parameter

```
clearDirectory(PATH, true);
```

> Use with caution, this will actually delete files

Comment: The most amazing nickname/avatar I have ever seen. Respect Sir... mleko (rofl)